# discord.py keyword in stats and give role

Tags: python, discord.py

how do I make an event where it tracks a user's status so like "discord.gg"SACRP", and it gives them a role in my server. I have tried with a scan of the user's status and looked at the docs but still can't find out how to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `discord.Member.activity`. It returns a string of member's custom activity. So basically, you can check if the activity contains a specific keyword, if it is then you can add role to member. You can create a task for this to check members' custom activity periodically.
**Here is an example code:**

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(role id)
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in client.get_all_members() if 'specific keyword' in member.activity]

check_activity.start()
```

If you just want to give role to online members, you can use member.status. It returns online or offline or DND.

Also, you can create a text file to store all the members that you give that role, and you can check again if they still have the specific keywords in their activity:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(role id)
    file = open('role_members.txt', 'r')
    member_list = [str(member.id) for member in client.get_all_members() if not str(member.status) == 'offline' and 'specific keyword' in member.activity]
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[:-1] not in member_list:
            member = await client.guilds[0].get_member(int(line))
            await member.remove_roles(role)
    a_file = open('role_members.txt', 'a')
    for member_id in member_list:
        await client.guilds[0].get_member(int(member_id)).add_roles(role)
        a_file.write(member_id + '\n')
            
        
check_activity.start()
```